# jquery attr behaviour in version 1.6

Tags: jquery, attributes, prop

I have made a page h[ere](http://pradyut.dyndns.org/newAlbum.jsp#uid=9&aid=20&imgid=84)

It was working fine with version 1.5

now with 1.6 i m getting this error in firebug

```
 elem.getAttribute is not a function
 [Break On This Error] ret = elem.getAttribute( name );
```

and in chrome almost the same

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'getAttribute'
```

How do rectify it??
Do i have to change everything to prop as in jquery 1.6 api
http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: What is the jQuery call that leads to the error?

Comment: I dont have any idea what has caused problem???

Comment: Here the reason is explained:

  http://edgarinvillegas.wordpress.com/2011/05/10/upgrading-to-jquery-1-6-troubleshooting/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, I think, in your library `jquery.getUrlParam.js`.  This has lines like the following:

```
if ($(this).attr("nodeName")=="#document") {
```

This worked under jQuery <= 1.5, because `attr` used both properties and attributes.  jQuery 1.6 has cleared this confusion up, which has created some problems for code that relied on this behaviour.  This is an example of code that has broken because of the change.

The correction would be

```
if (this.nodeName === "#document") {
```

You should be able to fix this in your code; it's probably also wise to report it to the plugin author.

A further point is that jQuery should probably give a better error message when trying `attr` on the `document` object, because the `document` node (unlike element nodes), does not have a `getAttribute` method.  This is the cause of your mysterious error message.

---

**Edit 11 May** The error here looks like being fixed in jQuery 1.6.1.  [This commit](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/4526c8b0a05ea16397a0640875bfbb54645a9482) to the jQuery source means that jQuery falls back on the `prop` method if the selected node does not have a `getAttribute` method.

This, along with [the other changes in 1.6.1](http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/jquery/~3/JA7dGZinLIU/) should make upgrading from <1.6 to 1.6.1 seamless.

Comment: yup that did it... thanks for the help...was a cumbersome library and i was not using it although...

Comment: do you think this is a bug or a jquery improvement... i have no idea although ...;-)

Comment: Maybe this is useful for you:  
http://edgarinvillegas.wordpress.com/2011/05/10/upgrading-to-jquery-1-6-troubleshooting/